# Как подключится к базе MongoDB, которая лежит на удаленном сервере?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mongodb, nosql, windows-server-2012

Проблема заключается вот в чем: я создал на portal.azure.com виртуальную машину (HPC Pack 2012 R2 on Windows Server 2012 R2), после чего поставил туда MongoDB, создал базу, коллекции. Но вот когда на домашнем ПК пробую получить доступ к серверу, то ничего не получается (из проложения ASP.NET MVC). Читал что нужно как-то добавить в файл конфигов ІР-адресса, или через bind_ip, но почему-то не получается сделать это.
Не знаю что делать, помогите кто чем может.

Comment: bind_ip = 0.0.0.0 пробовали вставлять в конфигурацию Mongo?

Comment: как это сделать?

Comment: В папке с mongodb должен быть какой-нибудь конфигурационный файл .cfg или .conf, что-то подобное. Вот там нужно одну строку в которой уже стоит 127.0.0.1 заменить на 0.0.0.0, если она там есть.

Comment: нет такого файла (искал в C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin - сюда установил MongoDB). Может еще где-то может быть?

Answer (score 1):

1. Укажите в конфигурационном файле mongod.cfg

   bindIp: 0.0.0.0
2. Перезапустите MongoDB
3. Проверьте/Откройте порт 27017 на firewall сервера.

PS: Рекомендуется открывать порт только для заданного IP, иначе база будет открыта для публичного доступа.

Comment: ну и пароль не забудьте на базу поставить, тем более, что наружу будет торчать